# Browser Extension to track my google activity

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-extension

I've been wanting to build a browser extension and recently found one that sort of does some of the functionality that I want.

http://answr.com/for-software-engineers/

I want my browser extension to watch what I google, and to pipe that to a server so I don't lose any useful links again.

How do browser extensions track what you google and what website your on.

Any direction, blog articles, or how-to's are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please give google's post a read first: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

I think this feature wouldn't be too difficult. In Chrome, extensions have a content script and background script. Think of it as client -> server running on your browser. The extension's content script will be loaded on every frame that you open and will have access to the DOM. The background script is long-running process that can communicate to all content scripts.

To create the feature you're requesting, you'd have to have some data store for your search results that the extension will capture. That could be an external web API, an in-browser database associated with your extension, or localStorage associated with your extension.

Since your content script loads on load of every new URL, it can easily check if window.location.href is google. Then, you'll have to keep a mapping or some sort of selector to figure out if you have changed the input on a search field:

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="both" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: none; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) transparent;">
```

Here, your script could look for $('input.gsfi');

Capture the changed value on form submit and send it to your background script which can handle storing the query to your data store of choice.

p.s., I'd guess your original question was down voted because it is vaguely a product/feature request with very vague requirements :)